# Index setup for multiple WHERE clauses with LIKE and IN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following columns:

`id | group_id | f_name | s_name`

I need to be able to filter by group_id and simultaneously by the name colums with LIKE (exact or post wildcard) like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users
WHERE
    users.group_id IN (7, 42, 1337)
    AND
    (users.f_name LIKE 'Test%' OR users.s_name LIKE 'Test%')
```

Both parts of the AND clause individually make good use of individual indices set on each of the 3 searched columns.

Together though the query get very slow. To a point where it is considerably faster to skip the group_id filter and do that on the database client side which surely goes against the core idea behind relational databases.

I tried using indices over multiple columns but I don't quite see how any could apply here.

A solution should work on sqlite3.

This is set to allow LIKE to use the indices for sqlite3: `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;`

Comment: Without actually looking at query plans, I would expect indexes on `(group_id, f_name)` and `(group_id, s_name)` to be the most useful with that query.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, but the fastest method is probably a more complicated query:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.group_id = 7 AND u.f_name LIKE 'Test%'
 OR u.s_name LIKE 'Test%')
UNION ALL
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.group_id = 7 AND u.s_name LIKE 'Test%' AND u.f_name NOT LIKE 'Test%'
UNION ALL
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.group_id = 42 AND u.f_name LIKE 'Test%'
 OR u.s_name LIKE 'Test%')
UNION ALL
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.group_id = 42 AND u.s_name LIKE 'Test%' AND u.f_name NOT LIKE 'Test%'
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.group_id = 1337 AND u.f_name LIKE 'Test%'
 OR u.s_name LIKE 'Test%')
UNION ALL
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.group_id = 1337 AND u.s_name LIKE 'Test%' AND u.f_name NOT LIKE 'Test%';
```

In particular, this should be able to make use of indexes on `users(group_id, s_name)` and `users(group_id, f_name)`.

Each of the subqueries in the `UNION ALL` can use a different index.  The way this is structured, there should be no duplicates (it does, however, assume that `f_name` is never `NULL`).

Comment: This solution indeed is rather fast using these two indices. Thank you! The problem is that I need to eventually create an SQLAlchemy or similar application around this. Not sure if this solution easily translates to maintainable code for that. Makes me question storing all entries in the same table. Maybe storing each group in a separate table is better... Though storing the same data format in different tables doesn't seem clean either. Not sure...

Comment: @iBent . . . You might find that two separate subqueries -- one on each name and all `group _id`s -- meets your performance needs.